# Internet server not configured, ошибка в Urbackups client

Tags: ubuntu, bash, резервное-копирование

Я столкнулся с ошибкой при установке Urbackups client на Ubuntu 22.04. В админ панеле сервера показывает что мой пк выключен

Скрин ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст ошибки:

```
lolka0d@asus:/usr/local/share/urbackup$ systemctl status urbackupclientbackend.service 
× urbackupclientbackend.service - UrBackup Client backend
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/urbackupclientbackend.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-10-24 00:27:48 EEST; 4min 37s ago
    Process: 9485 ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/urbackupclientbackend --config /etc/default/urbackupclient --no-consoletime (code=exited, status=2)
   Main PID: 9485 (code=exited, status=2)

жов 24 00:27:47 asus systemd[1]: Started UrBackup Client backend.
жов 24 00:27:48 asus urbackupclientbackend[9485]: ERROR: Internet server not configured. Please configure "internet_server".
жов 24 00:27:48 asus systemd[1]: urbackupclientbackend.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
жов 24 00:27:48 asus systemd[1]: urbackupclientbackend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Хотя с urbackupsrv.service все в порядке:
Скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Текст:

```
lolka0d@asus:/usr/local/share/urbackup$ systemctl status urbackupsrv.service 
● urbackupsrv.service - LSB: Server for doing backups
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/urbackupsrv; generated)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-10-23 23:59:47 EEST; 37min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
      Tasks: 18 (limit: 18922)
     Memory: 15.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/urbackupsrv.service
             └─2132 /usr/bin/urbackupsrv run --config /etc/default/urbackupsrv --daemon --pidfile /var/run/urbackupsrv.pid

жов 23 23:59:47 asus systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Server for doing backups...
жов 23 23:59:47 asus systemd[1]: Started LSB: Server for doing backups.
```

Если вы нуждаетесь в информации для решения проблемы - пишите я предоставлю!
Изменено:
Конфиг: /etc/default/urbackupclient:

```
lolka0d@asus:~$ sudo cat /etc/default/urbackupclient 
# Defaults for urbackup_client initscript
# sourced by /etc/init.d/urbackupclientbackend
# installed at /etc/default/urbackupclient by the maintainer scripts

#
# This is parsed as a key=value file
#

#logfile name
LOGFILE="/var/log/urbackupclient.log"

#Either debug,warn,info or error
LOGLEVEL=warn

#Max size of the log file before rotation
#Disable if you are using logrotate for
#more advanced configurations (e.g. with compression)
LOG_ROTATE_FILESIZE=20971520

#Max number of log files during rotation
LOG_ROTATE_NUM=10

#Tmp file directory
DAEMON_TMPDIR="/tmp"

# Valid settings:
#
# "client-confirms": If you have the GUI component the currently active user
#                    will need to confirm restores from the web interface.
#                    If you have no GUI component this will cause restores
#                    from the server web interface to not work
# "server-confirms": The server will ask the user starting the restore on 
#                    the web interface for confirmation
# "disabled":        Restores via web interface are disabled.
#                    Restores via urbackupclientctl still work
#
RESTORE=disabled

#If true client will not bind to any external network ports (either true or false)
INTERNET_ONLY=true
```

Comment: А что у вас в конфиге в пункте `internet_server`?

Comment: Может в /etc/default/urbackupclient?

Answer (score 0):

я редактировал файл  /usr/local/var/urbackup/data/settings.cfg
у меня был пустой internet_server

```
#Initial Settings. Changes will not be respected.
#48692563-17e4-4ccb-a078-f14372fdbe20
internet_mode_enabled=true
internet_server=192.168.11.130
internet_server_port=55415
internet_server_proxy=
internet_authkey=wr616FSS8Y
computername=009
```

после этих правок я смог запустить сервис

```
sudo service urbackupclientbackend start
```